# Dual head problem

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, 64-bit

I am running dual head on my laptop with two screens of different dimensions (1280 x 1024 and 1280 x 800). The video card is a Radeon x1200.

On booting the correct desktop background is displayed briefly and then it disappears to be replaced by black. If I drag a window round the screen(s) it leaves trails and if I close it the image of the window stays there (ie as a background). Not vital, but a pain. Any way to fix it?

It's AMD64 11.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to 11.10 made this problem go away.